# Parse Returns Unauthorized Error

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-server

I downloaded the Parse starter project for Swift, filled out the `Parse.setApplicationId()` method so it contained the App Id and the Master Key to the app I deployed through heroku, and when I ran it, I got the following errors:

> 2016-06-01 18:19:02.063 ParseStarterProject[66355:25475020] [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
>   2016-06-01 18:19:02.064 ParseStarterProject[66355:25475023] [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=100 "unauthorized" UserInfo={code=100, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "(null)", temporary=0, error=unauthorized, NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized}

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code :

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = kParseApplicationID
    $0.clientKey = kParseClientKey
    $0.server = kParseServerURL
    $0.localDatastoreEnabled = true
}
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```